# Umbraco 7, AfterUpdateDocumentCache event is deprecated

Tags: events, deprecated, umbraco7

I look that the signature of `umbraco.content.AfterUpdateDocumentCache` event uses `umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.Document` object. Unfortunatelly it is deprecated in "Umbraco 7".
What is the new event?

I'm the same issue in `umbraco.content.AfterClearDocumentCache` event.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-3462

According to this thread, answered by members of the Umbraco team, the AfterUpdateDocumentCache should still be used and the deprecated parameters are safely ignorable

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't appear  there's any analog for `umbraco.content.AfterUpdateDocumentCache`  in the umbraco7 code.

It seems you may have to reconsider you implementation approach to the available events hanging off `Umbraco.Core.Services.ContentService`

Looking at the u7 implementation of `ContentService.Publish`, for example, this call the internal `SaveAndPublishDo` which shows that the  PreviewXML and the ContentXML disc caches are called before firing the Saved and Published (via Umbraco.Core.Publishing.PublishingStrategy) events.  I presume the old `umbraco.content.AfterUpdateDocumentCache` was a single event that happened after both of the aforemented events. In it's absence - i believe you may have to watch for the saved/published/deleted events separately.
I can see that there are a bunch of events that would cause the cache update and it'd be a pain to wire them up separately - but maybee a different approach specific to the granularity of the available events is an upgrade?!

It may also help to backtrack from `Umbraco.Core.Cache.CacheRefresherBase` where i see there are events like OnCacheUpdated. They exist end do fire - though i'm not sure if or where they are publicly exposed.

This is probably more appropriate as a comment (i need more pts) as it's not a 100% resolution to your question. Hopefully it may be helpful to nudge in the right direction?

Comment: I'm interesting to `Umbraco.Core.Cache.CacheRefresherBase` class. I will try to use it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use AfterUpdateDocumentCache in Umbraco 7 but noticed two issues. First of these is double firing this event. Second problem is that I retrieve the same not modified content when rendering page just in this event.

Then I decided to use CacheRefresherBase and CacheUpdate event but still have the same problem. Probably due to additional cache refreshing propagation.

The only workaround I see is to use Thread.Sleep in the new Task and perform purging url a little bit later.